# Delay with ImportXML via Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to do web scraping using Google Spreadsheet with XPath. However, the page needs a few seconds to load.

This is the returned XML before loaded:

```
<div class=”game_list”>
    <div class=”loading”>
        <p class=”msg”>Please wait, the result is being loaded…</p>
```

This is the XML after loaded:

```
<div class=”game_list”>
    <div id=”game1”>…</div>
    <div id=”game2”>…</div>
    <div id=”game3”>…</div>
```

The problem is using ImportXML can only import the first XML. So I cannot scrape the detailed game info from game_list. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post your XPath?

Comment: the XPath is: //div[@class='game_list"]

Answer (score 1):

It seems page uses javascript to load data - then you have problem. To get this data you need tool which simulates browser and runs javascript - like `Selenium` - or you have to analyze javascript code (which loads that data) and find direct url of loaded data.